# Ionic/Angular: Acualizing a view when database changed

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have got a little info-card in my app, which shows the actual speaker on the stage with a little picture.

How can I make this stay actual? I am going to take the changes in the database, when a new speaker is on stage. When the database changed, the informations inside the app should change, too. How can I make this happen?

.html:

```
 <h2>Jetzt am Podium:</h2>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item >
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{ item.picture }}">
      </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
        <p><strong>Beitrag: </strong> {{ item.redebeitrag }}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

.ts-File:

```
load() : void
   {
      this.http
      .get('www...com/.../retrieve-data.php')
      .subscribe((data : any) =>
      {
         console.dir(data);
         this.items = data;
      },
      (error : any) =>
      {
         console.dir(error);
      });
   }
```

Edit: 
I am working with the pull-down Refresher Method from Ionic. It works well. But how can I make it actualizing doRefresh() in the Background?

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      this.load();
      refresher.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: Use a websocket or long polling.

Comment: @bc1105 Can you give me an example? I am new in angularjs. Thank you!